# I can’t resize anything in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I’m currently working on animating a PSD file on after effects. I imported a video into after effects and manipulated it, I’m not sure what I did but out of nowhere the video disappeared. So I went into a subfolder and re added the video there. But once I went back to the whole document, the other video appeared but now I can’t resize them, none of the little square in the corners appear. But when I go into the sub folder it works there, I can resize things. What can I do to be able to resize everything again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you pressed <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> ? This toggles the wireframe views around each object on or off?

Also, you might find this beginner's guide to AE helpful. It's old but it definitely helped me:

https://www.videocopilot.net/basic/